# Play Slick: How to inject DbConfigProvider in tests

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

I am using Play 2.5.10, Play-slick 2.0.2, and my activator-generated project comes with scalatest and code like this:

```
class TestSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {...}
```

I managed to test routes/Actions; now I would **test DAO methods** on a lower level. I searched the web and SO for a solution, and could not find any that is still up-to-date. A DAO signature is like this:

```
class TestDAO @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile]
```

so I need to pass it the `dbConfigProvider` thing.
For some reason I can't inject the provider into the tests like we do in controllers (no error, tests just won't run):

```
class TestSpec @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {...}
```

The [Play-Slick docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick) say we can alternatively use a global lookup

```
val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
```

but it won't work directly because

> There is no started application

and link to an example project doing that:

```
class TestDAOSpec extends Specification {
  "TestDAO" should {
    "work as expected" in new WithApplicationLoader {   // implicit 'app'
      val app2dao = Application.instanceCache[TestDAO].apply(app)
```

but I could never find the `WithApplicationLoader`. Instead, there seems to be a `WithApplication`:

```
class TestDAOSpec extends Specification {
  "TestDAO" should {
    "work as expected" in new WithApplication() {   // implicit 'app'
      val app2dao = Application.instanceCache[TestDAO].apply(app)
```

but then I get

> Type mismatch: expected a play.api.Application, got: play.Application.

At this point I lost hope.

**How can I test a DAO?**

N.B. I don't need to switch databases for testing (I handle this via config), I just want to access the default database in tests.

Comment: You just need an application in scope, so mix in a `OneAppPerSuite` or `OneAppPerTest`. See [here](https://github.com/sake92/PlayGuiceExample/blob/master/test/dao/PersonDAOImplSpec.scala#L17).

Comment: I do `with OneAppPerSuite`, yet I get this. One solution I found was to `import play.api.Play.current` in the `WithApplication()` version, then it works but I get a deprecation warning.

Comment: It worked with that example, thanks a lot. I overrid `PlaySpec` to include all that mysterious mess. I am totally disgusted by how this is so incredibly complicated. Override the implicit app that comes from nowhere, `GuiceApplicationBuilder`, repeat the conf you already have in your config for no apparent reason, `instanceCache`, whaaat?? And if I can copy and paste that after sooo many hours trying everything else, why is that not already in the framework???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
lazy val appBuilder: GuiceApplicationBuilder = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Mode.Test) 
lazy val injector: Injector = appBuilder.injector()
lazy val dbConfProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider = injector.instanceOf[DatabaseConfigProvider]
```

Comment: It works and answers the question directly. For other viewers, this is to be inserted into an extension of `PlaySpec` like in this example https://github.com/sake92/PlayGuiceExample/blob/master/test/dao/PersonDAOImplSpec.scala#L17. `DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](app)` also works now that I know how to obtain my implicit `app`. But these few lines made me understand a lot of things, thanks.

Comment: It needs to run the play application, and we have to mock lots of things! What happened if we need to initiate and test only the repository layer?